# Can I deploy a Sharepoint 2010 blog on a plain ASP.NET hosting company?

Tags: deployment, blog

If I decide to host a blog using Sharepoint 2010 can any plain vanilla .NET 4.0 ASP.NET hosting company be OK or does the host need to support Sharepoint? Are Sharepoint stuff deployed when I deploy the app from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint Blogs runs on SharePoint infrastructure. They cannot run without apporpriate version of SharePoint installed on target environment.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you meet [system & hardware requirement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) for SharePoint 2010. I give you 2 the best SharePoint hosting:

1. [FpWeb](http://www.fpweb.net/)
2. [RackSpace](http://www.rackspace.com/)

Comment: Most shared hosting will not let you install SharePoint. Dedicated hosting will generally let you do what you want.